# Why is using a Tuple faster than a List in this example?

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I wrote a C# class that is populating a "List of List of doubles" with some data (doesn't matter what the data is, for now it can just be some garbage:)), for testing purposes:

Here is the code:

```
    class test
    {
    public test()
    {
       _myListOfList = new List<List<double>>(1000000);
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _myListOfList.Capacity; i++)
        {
            _myListOfList.Add(
                new List<double>(3) { i, 10*i, 100*i}
                ); //Populate the list with data
        }
    }

    private List<List<double>> _myListOfList;
}
```

I compared the speed of execution of this code with the following: (replacing the List of double by a Tuple)

```
    class test
    {
    public test()
    {
       _myListOfTuple = new List<Tuple<double, double, double>>(1000000);
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _myListOfTuple.Capacity; i++)
        {
            _myListOfTuple.Add(
                new Tuple<double, double, double>(i, 10 * i, 100 * i)
                ); //Populate the list with data
        }
    }

    private List<Tuple<double, double, double>> _myListOfTuple;
}
```

Turns out that using the Tuple seems to be considerably faster. I ran this piece of code for different List sizes (from 200,000 elements -> 5 millions elements in the list) and here are the results I get:

[image: graph]

I cannot really get my head around this one. How come I get such a significant difference? Using a Tuple that stores object of the same type (doubles here) doesn't make much sense. I'd rather use a List/array to do that: what am I doing wrong? Is there a way I can make case #1 run as fast/faster than case #2?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this surprising at all?  It takes a lot more work to handle storing an arbitrarily large number of objects than it does to store exactly 3 objects.

Comment: Overheads. For one thing, how much space would you expect a tuple of doubles occupy compared to a list? What fields for each type would you expect them to have internally?

Comment: scaling even small differences up enough make them look large..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between `new Tuple<double, double, double>(i, 10 * i, 100 * i)` and `new List<double>(3) { i, 10*i, 100*i}`.

The first one is super simple - just 3 assignments:

```
public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3) {
    m_Item1 = item1;
    m_Item2 = item2;
    m_Item3 = item3;
}
```

The second one is actually transformed by compiler into 3 `Add` method calls:

```
var temp = new List<double>(3);
temp.Add(i);
temp.Add(10 * i);
temp.Add(100 * i);
```

`Add` is much more than just an assignment:

```
public void Add(T item) {
    if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
    _items[_size++] = item;
    _version++;
}
```

More code to run, slower execution. Quite simple..

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer.. it makes a lot of sense! As @Tigran suggested, I replaced the List with an array (new int[3] { i, 10 * i, 100 * i }) and I'm getting very similar results in terms of speed :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @Marcin's answer it's true that even initializing `List<T>` by initializer list IL still has `Add()` function inside, even if you specify initially, during construction, [Capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) of a list. Like you did in your example.

> Is there a way I can make case #1 run as fast/faster than case #2?

The possible solution may be direct assignment to members:

```
list[0] = 
list[1] = 
list[2] =
```

In this case IL look like this:

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Double>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // list
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // list
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0009:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 3F 
IL_0012:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Double>.set_Item
IL_0017:  ldloc.0     // list
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0019:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 24 40 
IL_0022:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Double>.set_Item
IL_0027:  ldloc.0     // list
IL_0028:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0029:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 59 40 
IL_0032:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Double>.set_Item
IL_0037:  ret
```

`set_Item` is faster as it's a simple assignment.

Or, use simple [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx). Performance *should* be better. Still, with those kind of things, like A vs B speed, the real answer one gets only after concrete measurement.